# Redisson - Queue capacity / documentation

Tags: java, redis, redisson

Is there any decent documentation for redisson, or best practice?

I'm using `.getBlockingQueue()` which allows for `offer()` and `put()`, but I have no idea what the capacity of the queue is. I'd like to set it to expand as needed, but without that I presume I probably need to have some persistence if I try to `offer()` the item and the queue is full.

Since the documentation seems so sparse, I find it difficult to use with much confidence as to what to expect.

Comment: using q.remainingCapacity() returns 2147483647, but the way it acts seems to make me think it will only accept a queue item if a thread is polling.

Comment: I have updated an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RBlockingQueue` currently is "unbounded" this is the reason why `remainingCapacity` returns Integer.MAX. But it's bounded only by Redis server memory size. I'm thinking about introduction a bounded queue with custom length.

**UPDATE**: Since Redisson 2.3.0 version it supports [bounded blocking queue](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson/wiki/7.-distributed-collections/#711-bounded-blocking-queue) which correctly count `remainingCapacity`